React native expo emulator force closed
When I try to run npm run android, the app opened and then shows this screen:

Then it immediately force closes the app. How can I fix this?

what did you pass into font-weight?

welcome: {
fontWeight: 700,
}

It's in style or given as text component prop?

share some code of where you gave fontweight.

return (


...
Login
           ...

...


)
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
welcome: {
    fontWeight: '700',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 32,
    color: '#F47323'
}

})

This error comes when you apply fontWeight as a number. ex: fontWeight: 600
but in the react-native stylesheet, you have to apply fontWeight as a string
fontWeight:"600"

